# HTML5/JavaScript Windows Store App packaged using VS2013 vs VS2017

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a HTML5/JavaScript Store project built on VS2013 using WinJS2.0 and AngularJS. The app is pretty matured at this stage and runs fine both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. However, when I try to built the same project using VS2017 I am running into issues with following objects

1. MSPointerEvent
2. execUnsafeLocalFunction

From what I understand is Windows Store App built using HTML/JavaScript using Edge underneath to execute. So why does it matter if I am using a different IDE to build the package. IDE is not performing any compilation.
Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed from a Windows Store app (W8.1, backed by IE) to a UWP app (W10, backed by Edge). VS2013 can't create UWP apps and VS2017 can't create Windows Store apps, so you must have ported.

In particular, pointer events are now a w3c standard, and the MS-prefixed versions are removed from EdgeHtml in favor of standardized pointer events. See [Pointer Event Updates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn304886.aspx)

The execUnsafeLocalFunction has been removed in favor of a new security model. See [Keep your app secure – Setting Application Content URI Rules (ACURs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/hwa-access-features#keep-your-app-secure-setting-application-content-uri-rules-acurs)

Comment: Thank you Rob. Yes, I have ported. I have kept the same files but changed the project and app package settings. I was under the impression that the JS libraries will run smooth when packaged using VS2017 since the VS2013 package ran fine on Windows 10